# How to decorate typescript vue class component with an imported method?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I've recently started using vue class components with typescript and can't find a way to decorate a component class with imported utility method. I'm using `nuxt-property-decorator` to decorate my component.

I've tried adding the method like I'd do it in vue component without typescript:

```
import doSomething from './somewhere';

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            doSomething,// I'd do this without typescript, works as expected
        },
    }
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import {Component} from 'nuxt-property-decorator';
    import doSomething from './somewhere';

    @Component
    export default class MyCustomClass extends Vue {
        doSomething, // Doesn't, "Property or method doSomething is not defined on the instance but referenced during render..."

        hacky() {
            return doSomething(); // I guess I could do it this way, but this looks like a very hacky way
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this problem was to simply use `@Component` to decorate the component with methods:

```
<script lang="ts">
    @Component({
        methods: {
            preventContextMenu,
        },
    })
    export default class MyCustomClass extends Vue {
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I was using `vue-property-decorator`. From what I know the `nuxt-property decorator` is based on it.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but if you want to run something on component init you can use `mounted` inside the component. This is lifecycle hook

Example:

```
        import doSomething from './somewhere';

        <script>
            export default {
                methods: {
                    doSomething,// I'd do this without typescript, works as expected
                },
            }
        </script>

        <script lang="ts">
            import Vue from 'vue';
            import {Component} from 'nuxt-property-decorator';
            import doSomething from './somewhere';

            @Component
            export default class MyCustomClass extends Vue {

                public mounted(){
                  doSomething...
                  // everything in this method  will be triggered on component load
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You are correct - `nuxt-property-decorator` is based on `vue-property-decorator`, but you didn't understood my question correctly. I don't want to use a component lifecycle hook, I want to use imported method in my component - `doSomething` is a method that I import from some es6 module and my issue is that I can't find a way to use this imported method, I'm sorry for my weak english skills.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
doSomething = doSomething
```

where all of your other methods are.